# Ideas to access my old Quantex (PATA) hard drive

Tags: laptop

Need help to find way to attach a some form of ribbon adapter to be able to retrieve files of this laptop. Laptop stopped working and quantex has been out of business for some time. Would like to access files like it is done with SATA drives. Any help would be deep appreciated. 
Thank you 
Raphael

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:
You need a "PATA" to "SATA" converter/adapter...

Use google to find one that suits your drive and power feed.

[Click here for a Google search, prepared for you](https://www.google.se/search?q=parallel%20ata%20to%20sata%20adapter)

Comment: Thank you  Hannu, I have a Sata adapter with power and it will not work. I will look for a pata adapter. Thanks again. They would not let me post a photo of the port that went into the mother board of the laptop. Raphael